# Linked assets disappearing randomly

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm building a static site with Gatsby and Contentful as a CMS and I've run into an extremely annoying problem. Assets (images and SVGs) that I link to my content randomly disappear after I rebuild with "gatsby develop". Contentful states that they're still "published" but they don't show up in GraphiQl. In addition to that, entire fields are disappearing. The only solution I found so far is to delete the assets in Contentful, reupload them, relink them and then gatsby develop.

In this screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eddWQ.jpg) you can see that all the "technologies"-assets are published but they don't show up in GraphiQl, even though they did earlier and I changed nothing in the meantime!

Has anyone ran into a similar issue and could offer some advice? Thanks!

```
            "node": {
            "title": "Progressive Web App",
            "technologies": [
              {
                "file": {
                  "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/xf0u4wogxlsc/2UiIMQsFTw4qEvQMzuMzFA/d79bee6cf7655380350634d065564469/gatsby.svg"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
         "node": {
            "title": "WordPress Site",
            "technologies": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "Portfolio",
            "technologies": null
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache with "gatsby clean" solves this issue.